# How to test a regular Javascript file in a React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs

I'm creating a React application that also has a folder of helper functions to use later. The helper functions are written in plain JS. I created a test file for the helper functions but when I run tests I only see the App.test.js results.

I can't tell what I'm missing. Below is the helper function test file:

```
import { IsValidBinary } from "./validityFunctions";

test("01101 should be binary", () => {
  const binString = "01101";
  const isValid = IsValidBinary(binString);
  expect(isValid).toBe(true);
});
```

Comment: What is the name of your js testfile?

Comment: @ShahinNazer The file is named validityFunction.test.js

Comment: I think what you are missing is a describe; inside which you should have the callback with the test function